# Soundcloud track only playing in flash despite originally being an mp3

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, mp3, soundcloud

I have a track that only seems to play with flash in my page. If assign the source stream to a audio element in my page i get nothing. While if I use `SC.stream(...)` the player imbeds a flash element in the page to play the song.

```
SC.stream("/tracks/127087965", function(sound){
  sound.play();
});
```

The interesting thing is that the song's `original_format` format of the track is mp3.

Is there any way to request a version of the song that will play with an `<audio>` tag?

In short I only want to use the HTML5 audio source, flash is not an option, and if the track is only accessable though flash, I want to know how to detect that when I call `SC.track(...)`.

Permalink: http://soundcloud.com/octobersveryown/drake-trophies

Comment: Did you tried the SoundCloud Widget ?

Comment: The widget would create a iFrame in the background, I don't believe it would change the sound playing in flash. I mean to look into more of it's features though.

Comment: I think when using their widget, they do a detection : if you have flash player you'll get flash version otherwise the html5 version (for mobile devices at least). Try it with google chrome mobile device emulator, you can disable flash player also.

Comment: My objective is to always use the HTML5 source. If it is available, I don't want to use flash. If it's not I want to be able to find out in my SC.track(...) call.

Comment: Take a look here : [HTML5 Widget API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/html5-widget-api).